# Java AWT Swing doesn't draw my frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to build a Java game on Eclipse. But I did some part on NetBeans. My problem is, the pages I made in NetBeans are shown correctly, whenever I go to the page it draws. But I did the game page by myself on Eclipse and it does not draw it. However, when I move the panel around it flashes my character and items then disappear. I think the problem is related to my code so here it is:

```
public class GameFrame extends Menu implements ActionListener{

    public Player player;
    Timer timer;
    Image bgIcon;

    JFrame frame ;
    JPanel mypanel;
    JLabel label ;
    public GameFrame(Player playah) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        mypanel =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        label = new JLabel("");

        player =playah;
        addKeyListener(new InputManager());
        timer = new Timer(50,this);
        timer.start();
        bgIcon = new ImageIcon(".\\Assets\\map.png").getImage();

        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bgIcon));
        mypanel.add(label);

        frame.add(mypanel);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mypanel.setVisible(true);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        frame.paintAll(g);
        //g.drawImage(bgIcon, GameManager.Instance.levelController.moveDisX, GameManager.Instance.levelController.moveDisY, null);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        GameManager.Instance.levelController.items.get(2).draw(g2d);
        GameManager.Instance.levelController.items.get(3).draw(g2d);
        GameManager.Instance.levelController.items.get(4).draw(g2d);
        GameManager.Instance.levelController.enemies.get(0).draw(g2d);
        player.draw(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
    }       
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `frame.paintAll(g);` is a bad idea and so is `g2d.dispose();` in the context you're provided

Comment: 1) `g2d.dispose();` Don't dispose of any graphics instance you did not create. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You should use `paintComponent`